# Moving from document ready to js file class/object

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, object, ready

I was doing a lot of mocking of a layout page. I wrote lots of javascript using $(document).ready in the header to test.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.errorPopup').hide();
    $('#account').mask('9999-9999-9999-9999');
    $('#code').mask('9999');

    $("#form").validate({
                errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                    $('.errorPopup').show();

        },
        success: function (label, element) {
            $('.errorPopup').hide();
        },
        rules: {           
            "account": {
                required: true
                },
            "code": {
                required: true,
                max:1000
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "account": {
                required: "Account is required."
            },
            "code": {
                required: "Code is required",
                max: "Sorry only 1000 max"

            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) { 
            return false; 
        }
    });
});
```

Now I have to add it to the main.js file that site use and everything is organized in class/objects.

//main.js

```
var checkAccount = {
     init: function(holder){
     messages = holder;
     $('elment1').click(//do something);
     $('elment2').click(//do something);
     },
     someAction: function(misc) ...  
}
```

How would I write my stuff in that format? How would I have it behave like before in $document.ready()?

THanks

Comment: The short of it is you make it into a class/object and initialize it on doc ready

Comment: I am not the best person to give you an answer because my understanding of it is not that deep

Comment: Why don't you just put your `checkAccount` inside `$(document).ready` ?

Comment: how would i structure the object? init is like the constructor? Can you write an answer showing how you'd do it exactly